# GUI  с возможностью перемещения объектов

Tags: java

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить следущую задачу. Мне надо нарисовать прямоугольный объект и чтобы была возможность перетаскивать его по экрану. Как можно это реализовать? И где можно про это почитать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подойдет http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/ ?

Comment: да пока не особо понятно, где там рисуется объект и как реализуется перемещение мышью, захват объекта мышью и перемещение